# Issue with pushing and tracking in new Git Bash release

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I've had some difficulties since the new Git Bash got released for windows. I don't know whether I made a mistake or not. I could recreate the cases again, see the screenshots below.

[image: Photo_1]
[image: Photo_2]

First, I created a new dir, a non-empty README.txt file, then a new repository on github. I choose “…or push an existing repository from the command line” and paste these commands into my CLI:

```
git remote add origin 'remote repository URL'
git push -u origin main
```

And until this point everything was okay.

I created a new .txt file added and comitted to the local repo. As you can see I always double checked the current git status. I successfully pushed the amended file to the remote repo but still got: "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit". Then I tried:

`git push -u 'origin'`

and it finally cleaned the working tree and also showed the following:
"Branch 'main' set up to track remote branch 'main' from.."

After that I did almost the same process: delete 1 file, add and commit. Checking again the git status and it didn't show the expected "branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit". This time it should be shown before pushing otherwise I might have some troubles tracking my work.

Comment: None of your images show the name `origin/master`; they all show the name `origin/main`. Other than this disagreement between your question posted here and your images included here, there's no apparent actual problem. What do you think is *wrong* here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you created your repo but could you do `git pull origin master` or in your case maybe `git pull origin main`. This should update your local repo accordingly. After that you shouldn't get that message, unless of course someone else commits to the repo and you need to pull the changes.

Comment: Yes, I could pull it before pushing but still got the same message.